# Why does .bind() prepend the optional arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

The first time I used .bind() I was tripped up by the fact that the optional arguments passed to the bound function are prepended. This got me when I was trying to hand things off to anonymous event handling functions, sort of like this:

```
$('#example').on('change', function(arg1, arg2, evt) {
    console.log(evt, arg1, arg2);
}.bind(null, arg1, arg2));
```

The MDN for [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) mentions the prepending several times but never elaborates, so I'm curious as to why - why do I have to put `arg1` and `arg2` before the `evt` in the function arguments? Wouldn't *appending* be easier to understand and slightly more performant?

Comment: What is "optional" about those parameters? Nothing as far as Javascript is concerned. And by binding the parameters from the left you can be sure what order they will be processed in, whereas you have absolutely no idea what parameter a bound parameter will end up as if they'd be appended to the end of the parameters passed at call time.

Comment: Yes appending would be easier. and thats exactly whats happening here.  The passed arguments are appended to those that were bound previously

Comment: In this case, it's the evt argument that gets appended.

Comment: @deceze they're "optional" in that they're not required - I don't have give anything to bind() except a "thisArg".

Comment: Ah, the *additional arguments* passed to the *bind* method, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the additional bound parameters were *appended* to the call time arguments, the behaviour would be like this:

```
function foo(bar, baz) {}
const b = foo.bind(null, 42);

b();          // bar = 42
b('c');       // bar = 'c', baz = 42
b('c', 'd');  // bar = 'c', baz = 'd'
```

Meaning, it is unpredictable where your bound arguments will end up, which is arguably insane.

Prepending also makes more sense if you think of `bind` as [*partial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) or [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):  very loosely functionally speaking, `foo.bind(null, 42)` returns a *partially applied* function,
it turns `a -> b -> c` (a function which takes two values and returns a third)
into `b -> c` (a function which takes only one more value and returns another).

Comment: Very interesting - that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) produces a new function that, when called, invokes the function on which `.bind()` is called.

Let's name `f` the function you use in your code:

```
var g = function f(arg1, arg2, evt) {
    console.log(evt, arg1, arg2);
}.bind(null, arg1, arg2)
```

`bind()` produces a new function (stored in `g`) that accepts any number of arguments (one in this example).
`g` may be called with zero or more arguments.

Only the first argument of `bind()` is required; it is the object to be referenced as `this` inside the function returned by `bind()`. The other arguments of `bind()`, if exist, are always available in `g`.

They are `arg1` and `arg2` in this example and they are always passed to `f`. The other arguments of `f` are the arguments of `g` when it is called. There may be none, one or more.

It's the natural choice to put `arg1` and `arg2` as the first arguments in the call to `f` and the rest of the list (the arguments passed to `g`) at the end.

If `arg1` and `arg2` are passed as the last arguments to `f` you have to check `arguments.length` inside `f` to find the last two arguments and its code becomes cumbersome.